# What is the easiest way to open the folder containing the current file by the default explorer of the OS?

Tags: files, directories

What is the easiest way to open the folder containing the current file by the default explorer of the OS (e.g. explorer.exe in the case of Windows OS)?

Comment: I have a hunch (browse-url-of-file default-directory) would do it, that works on osx with finder, I would think it would work with windows, but can't test it.

Comment: @JordonBiondo it works! Please convert your comment to an answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using `browse-url-of-file` should work when given a directory.

You could implement a command that opens the directory of the current file like this:

```lisp
(defun browse-file-directory ()
  "Open the current file's directory however the OS would."
  (interactive)
  (if default-directory
      (browse-url-of-file (expand-file-name default-directory))
    (error "No `default-directory' to open")))
```

Then <kbd>M-x</kbd> <kbd>browse-file-directory</kbd> should open up the directory in your OS's file browser.

Comment: There has been an small incompatibility with emacs 25.* in Windows, but the solution works fine with emacs 26.1 on Windows.

Comment: Would it be possible to get the file selected, like in VS? See trick 20 in https://dev.to/devmount/23-lesser-known-vs-code-shortcuts-as-gif-80

Comment: @user3341592 Use `(shell-command (concat "start explorer /e,/select,\"" (replace-regexp-in-string "/" "\\\\" (buffer-file-name)) "\""))`. See: https://davidcapello.com/blog/emacs/emacs-how-to-locate-the-current-buffer-in-windows-explorer/

Comment: This opens dired in Emacs 28 instead of the OS's file browser.

Comment: @scribe: that probably depends on your `broser-url-...` settings and it's probably not limited to Emacs 28.

Comment: Do you mind elaborating more in the browser URL settings part?

Comment: @scribe Just change `browse-url-of-file` to `browse-url` in the code.

Answer (score 7):

For MS Windows:

Load library [`w32-browser.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/w32-browser.el) and use command `w32explore`. It does exactly what you are requesting.  See [MS Shell Execute](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MsShellExecute).

If you also use [**Dired+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) then `M-RET` on a file or dir name in Dired [opens Windows Explorer](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/OperatingOnFilesInDired#w32-browser) for it.

Answer (score 2):

Run `shell-command` (<kbd>M</kbd>+<kbd>!</kbd>) with the default explorer program and the current folder, e.g. for MS Windows, `explorer .`

Answer (score 2):

```lisp
(defun open-this-buffer-directory-on-windows()
  (interactive)
  (shell-command "explorer .")
  )
```

Comment: Welcome to Emacs.SE!  Could you please a) format your code for the site, and b) provide enough commentary to explain what your code is doing.

Comment: For some obscure reason, explorer appeared to return 1 even on success. Ended up having to replace ```shell-command``` with ```start-process```, _e.g._ ```(start-process "EXPLORER" nil "explorer" ".")```.

Answer (score 0):

copy the full path to the clipboard at first:

```lisp
;; you need install xsel under Linux
;; xclip has some problem when copying under Linux
(defun copy-yank-str (msg &optional clipboard-only)
  (unless clipboard-only (kill-new msg))
  (cond
   ;; display-graphic-p need windows 23.3.1
   ((and (display-graphic-p) x-select-enable-clipboard)
    (x-set-selection 'CLIPBOARD msg))
   (t (with-temp-buffer
        (insert msg)
        (shell-command-on-region (point-min) (point-max)
                                 (cond
                                  ((eq system-type 'cygwin) "putclip")
                                  ((eq system-type 'darwin) "pbcopy")
                                  (t "xsel -ib")))))))

(defun cp-fullpath-of-current-buffer ()
  "copy full path into the yank ring and OS clipboard"
  (interactive)
  (when buffer-file-name
    (copy-yank-str (file-truename buffer-file-name))
    (message "file full path => clipboard & yank ring")))
```