# Open the directory of currently opened file using the OS's file explorer

Tags: files, directories

This is essentially the same question as [this one](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/7742/25462). But the accepted answer there opens Dired for me in Emacs 28 while previously it opened Caja. Could someone offer a fix? I tried commenting there but no one responded.

**Edit**: I adopted the accepted answering like this:

```lisp
(defun caja (interactive)
  (let ((process-connection-type nil))
    (start-process "" nil "caja"
    (url-file-directory buffer-file-name))))
```

Comment: Did you try the `shell-command` method in another answer of that question?

Comment: Where you could add a `&` to open it asynchronously (see `shell-command` docstring).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably a better alternative (for which I have defined a command in my dotfile) to the answer in the comments, because it does not open a process buffer, is:

```
  (let ((process-connection-type nil))
    (start-process ""
                   nil
                   "open"
                   (url-file-directory buffer-file-name))))
```

(I am not completely sure about "open" because I am on GNU/linux, but I found  that solution for OS X in the answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/60835/how-can-i-open-a-file-in-its-default-application-from-the-command-line-in-os-x/60836)).

Comment: `open` would be the correct command on OS X. Use `xdg-open` instead on desktop GNU/linux.

Comment: Ah thanks... for some reason I read/interpreted OS X in the question, which of course is not the case. Indeed `xdg-open` is what I use here too..